# How to compare a population proportion to a probability of success of 1?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, proportion

I would like to assess whether my population proportion (P1) is significantly different from a hypothesized value (P0). I would usually use a binomial test to test this hypothesis. However this time my hypothesized probability of success P0 is 1 and it seems that the null hypothesis (true probability of success is equal to 1) is always rejected unless the population proportion (P1) is also exactly equal to 1.

Is there maybe a more appropriate test to test this if my population proportion differs from 1 ?

Thank you all in advance for your kind help !

Comment: If P0 was really 1, then a single observation of 0 would disprove this hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

If you get different outcomes, it means that the probability of getting a particular outcome is not one. Therefore, you reject, with certainty, that the probability could be one.

**EXAMPLE**

Pull fruit out of a basket, hypothesizing that there is a probability of $1$ that you will pull out an apple. If you ever pull out a banana, you *know* your hypothesis was wrong.